# Problema con estructuras

Tags: c++, estructuras

El programa consiste en introducir dos fechas y analizar cual es mayor. El problema es que siempre sale mayor la segunda fecha.(Exactamente sucede en el primer *else if*

)

```
#include<iostream> using namespace std;

typedef struct {
    int dia;
    int mes;
    int ano; }tFecha;

void rellenarDia(tFecha uno,tFecha dos); void rellenarMes(tFecha uno, tFecha dos); void rellenarAno(tFecha uno, tFecha dos);


int main() {
    tFecha uno;
    tFecha dos;
    rellenarDia(uno,dos);
    rellenarMes(uno,dos);
    rellenarAno(uno,dos);

    if(uno.ano > dos.ano)
    {
        cout << "La fecha 1 es mayor";
    }else if(uno.ano < dos.ano)
    {
        cout << "La fecha 2 es mayor";
    }else
    {
        if(uno.mes > dos.mes)
        {
            cout << "La fecha 1 es mayor";
        }else if(uno.mes < dos.mes)
        {
            cout << "La fecha 2 es mayor";
        }else
        {
            if(uno.dia > dos.dia)
            {
                cout << "La fecha 1 es mayor";
            }else if(uno.dia < dos.dia)
            {
                cout << "La fecha 2 es mayor";
            }else
            {
                cout << "Las fechas son iguales";
            }
        }
    } }

void rellenarDia(tFecha uno,tFecha dos) {
    cout << "Introduzca el dia de la fecha 1: ";
    cin >> uno.dia;
    cout << "Introduzca el dia de la fecha 2: ";
    cin >> dos.dia; }

void rellenarMes(tFecha uno, tFecha dos) {
    cout << "Introduzca el mes de la fecha 1: ";
    cin >> uno.mes;
    cout << "Introduzca el mes de la fecha 2: ";
    cin >> dos.mes; }

void rellenarAno(tFecha uno, tFecha dos) {
    cout << "Introduzca el año de la fecha 1: ";
    cin >> uno.ano;
    cout << "Introduzca el año de la fecha 2: ";
    cin >> dos.ano; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pasa los parametros por referencia:

```
void rellenarDia(tFecha &uno, tFecha &dos);
```

En tu codigo el objeto esta siendo pasado por valor. Entonces cuando llamas a la funcion para `rellenarDia`, `rellenarMes` o `rellenarAno` el valor se almacena en las variables miembro, pero cuando el control regresa a la funcion `main` los valores no se reflejan ya que son almacenados en una copia del objeto y no en el objeto original.

**Solucion:**

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef struct {
    int dia;
    int mes;
    int ano;
} tFecha;

// pasa los parametros por referencia
void rellenarDia(tFecha &uno, tFecha &dos);

void rellenarMes(tFecha &uno, tFecha &dos);

void rellenarAno(tFecha &uno, tFecha &dos);


int main() {
    tFecha uno;
    tFecha dos;
    rellenarDia(uno, dos);
    rellenarMes(uno, dos);
    rellenarAno(uno, dos);

    if (uno.ano > dos.ano) {

        cout << "La fecha 1 es mayor";
    } else if (uno.ano < dos.ano) {

        cout << "La fecha 2 es mayor";
    } else {
        if (uno.mes > dos.mes) {

            cout << "La fecha 1 es mayor";
        } else if (uno.mes < dos.mes) {

            cout << "La fecha 2 es mayor";
        } else {
            if (uno.dia > dos.dia) {

                cout << "La fecha 1 es mayor";
            } else if (uno.dia < dos.dia) {

                cout << "La fecha 2 es mayor";
            } else {

                cout << "Las fechas son iguales";
            }
        }
    }
}

// recibe parametros por referencia
void rellenarDia(tFecha &uno, tFecha &dos) {
    cout << "Introduzca el dia de la fecha 1: ";
    cin >> uno.dia;
    cout << "Introduzca el dia de la fecha 2: ";
    cin >> dos.dia;
}

// recibe parametros por referencia
void rellenarMes(tFecha &uno, tFecha &dos) {
    cout << "Introduzca el mes de la fecha 1: ";
    cin >> uno.mes;
    cout << "Introduzca el mes de la fecha 2: ";
    cin >> dos.mes;
}

// recibe parametros por referencia
void rellenarAno(tFecha &uno, tFecha &dos) {
    cout << "Introduzca el año de la fecha 1: ";
    cin >> uno.ano;
    cout << "Introduzca el año de la fecha 2: ";
    cin >> dos.ano;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Esto es c++, no c. Luego en vez de esto

```
typedef struct {
  int dia;
  int mes;
  int ano;
}tFecha;
```

Haz esto

```
struct tFecha{
  int dia;
  int mes;
  int ano;
};
```

Ahora bien...

> El programa consiste en introducir dos fechas y analizar cual es mayor.

El problema está en las funciones... sí,  en todas:

```
void rellenarDia(tFecha uno,tFecha dos);
```

Los parametros los pasas por valor, lo que sucede entonces es que al llamar a una función se hace una copia local de cada parámetro que es la que se modifica en la función... al finalizar la función la copia local se destruye... mientras que la versión original no sufre cambios.

La solución es tan sencilla como usar referencias:

```
void rellenarDia(tFecha & uno,tFecha & dos);
//                      ^            ^
```